# How to write a unit test for batch reader using mockito

Tags: jakarta-ee, mockito, batch-processing, spring-batch

I created my first batch reader and I intend to test my class with mockito. I do not know how to do this exactly. Below you will find my class "Trailreader" and my test class  "Trailreadertest" that I began to develop. I thank you in advance for your help.

Trailreader class:

```
public class Trailreader implements ItemReader<TrailreaderInfo> {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Trailreader.class);
    private static final int LIMIT = 10;

    @Value("#{configurationBatch.limit}")
    public String limitString;

    public String tableName;
    public int nbLimit;
    public List<Long> listToDelete;

    @Inject
    @Named("trailDao")
    public transient ITrailDao trailDao;

    public Trailreader() {
        super();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize
     */
    @PostConstruct
    public void initialize() {

        try {
            nbLimit = Integer.parseInt(limitString);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            nbLimit = LIMIT;
        }
    }


    @DoNotLog
    @Transactional
    @Override
    public TrailreaderInfo read() throws Exception, UnexpectedInputException, NonTransientResourceException {
        try {
            List<String> tableList = trailDao.getTablesList();
            for (String tableName : tableList) {
                List<Long> list_id = trailDao.getlist_idByDate(tableName);
                List<Long> listToDelete = new ArrayList<Long>();
                if (list_id.size() > nbLimit) {
                    int list_id_size = list_id.size();
                    int j = 0;
                    while (list_id_size > nbLimit) {
                        listToDelete.add(list_id.get(j));
                        list_id_size--;
                        j++;
                    }
                }
            }
            return new TrailreaderInfo(tableName, nbLimit, listToDelete);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOG.error(e.getClass().getName(), e.getMessage());
            throw new ParseException(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:test-applicationContext.xml" })
@DirtiesContext(classMode = ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
public class TrailreaderTest {
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TrailreaderTest.class);

    @InjectMocks
    protected transient Trailreader reader;

    @Inject
    @Named("trailDao")
    protected transient ITrailDao trailDao;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        LOG.info(TrailreaderTest.class.getSimpleName());
    }

    /**
     * Initialization method
     */
    @Transactional(value = Transactions.TX_MANAGER_READ_WRITE, readOnly = false)
    protected void initialization() {
        reader.trailDao = trailDao;
        reader.limitString = "10";
        reader.nbLimit = 10;

        reader.initialize();
    }

    @Test
    public void HistoryBackOfficeInfo() {
        initialization();   
    }   
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! You have posted everything we'd need to help you but one thing: what your problem is. Where are you stuck? Or... why the test is not working?

Comment: my problem is that I did not know how to test my class. what variables are initialized? how to test the read method? compare the result with the expected result?thank you for your help

Comment: If you are using mockito, you should mock the `Trailreader` dependencies (`ITrailDao`) and stub the methods `ITrailDao::getTablesList`and `ITrailDao::getlist_idByDate`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test your ItemReader then you need to mock its dependencies not the object itself.

So you need to mock the DAO. So that you can test the reader in the case the DAO return null value or empty list or some specific values...